# CakePHP dies instead of telling me the error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have CakePHP. But sometimes, if I make (usually syntax) error, it doesn't tell me where and what's wrong, it just dies and I get:

[image: sdf]

Why is that, and how can I get line number and error type instead?

Debug is on. Version 2.2.3

UPDATE1:

```
    Configure::write('Error', array(
        'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
        'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT,
        'trace' => true
    ));
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

And errors files:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

`app/tmp/error.log` had problems with permissions, after I `chmod -R 777 app/tmp/log/` I have the following stuff appearing:

```
2013-09-13 08:17:32 Error: Fatal Error (4): parse error in    [/Users/petarpetrov/jobsAdvent/sunshine/app/View/Themed/Jobsearch/Users/employer_setting.ctp, line 24]
2013-09-13 08:17:32 Error: [FatalErrorException] parse error
#0 /Users/petarpetrov/jobsAdvent/sunshine/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php(161):     ErrorHandler::handleFatalError(4, 'parse error', '/Users/petarpet...', 24)
#1 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleError(4, 'parse error', '/Users/petarpet...', 24, Array)
#2 /Users/petarpetrov/jobsAdvent/sunshine/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(926): call_user_func('ErrorHandler::h...', 4, 'parse error', '/Users/petarpet...', 24, Array)
#3 /Users/petarpetrov/jobsAdvent/sunshine/lib/Cake/Core/App.php(899): App::_checkFatalError()
#4 [internal function]: App::shutdown()
```

## 5 {main}

`/var/logs/apache2/error_log` has no new lines after such error.  However, I have the following things there:

```
[Thu Sep 12 12:43:37 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Sep 12 12:44:08 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint:     SSLSessionCache]
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1 for ServerName
PHP:  parse error in /private/etc/php.ini on line 1927
[Thu Sep 12 12:44:08 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Sep 12 12:44:08 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Sep 12 12:44:08 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8x configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 12 12:53:55 2013] [notice] child pid 467 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 12 12:53:55 2013] [notice] child pid 466 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 12 13:02:14 2013] [notice] child pid 468 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 12 13:02:33 2013] [notice] child pid 545 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 12 16:21:26 2013] [notice] child pid 463 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 12 16:21:28 2013] [notice] child pid 465 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Sep 13 10:14:50 2013] [notice] child pid 462 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Network Tab:

[image]

Comment: if you have debug on, there's no useful info in `/app/tmp/logs/error.log`?

Comment: do you have your debug set to 1 or higher in your Config/core.php file?

Comment: Sometimes I do, sometimes I don't have useful Info, but in any case, the problem here is that CakePHP just dies out, instead of displaying the error while in debug mode

Comment: Can you post the core code you have regarding errors and exceptions (that code starts with `Configure::write('Error'` and `Configure::write('Exception'` respectively)? And also, can you tell what files are in `app/View/Errors`? Have you made any changes to those files?

Comment: My best guess is that the `ExceptionRenderer` is not finding your error views. I haven't work with themed apps, so I can't help you there, but if you want to rule out that kind of error, go to `cakeroot/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer` and in the function `error500` change `$this->_outputMessage('error500');` for a simple `echo 'in here';exit;`. If the echo gets displayed, is a problem with finding the views (rollback the changes after verifying that).

Comment: Didn't work. Still getting the same `No Data Received` page.

Answer (score 2):

- Check app/tmp/logs/error.log
- Check the web server error and access logs!
- Check the Network tab in chrome and check the response and request there
- Or use something like Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to monitor the request and response
- Check what headers the application is returning

Comment: The problem here is not the error itself, but that CakePHP dies

Comment: I doubt that as I doubt that you have tried everything you've been told. If so please show us in your question what your log files (Cake,  Apache/Nginx, php) say and your request and response from Charles or at least Chromes network tab.

Comment: Thank you for still being here @burzum, I have added all the information I could find, according to your suggestions. I can see an error in the log file now, but I don't understand why the app shuts down, instead of showing the error in the browser.